# Find specified string in nested lists with recursion and add new

Tags: c#, recursion, nested-lists

I can’t write a function that takes 3 arguments `Func(ObservableCollection<Node> list, value_for_search, value_for_add)` were searched for all nested lists, and if the `Name` matches, one more level of data is added.

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Child { get; set; }
}
ObservableCollection<Node> nodes;
nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
{
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.1",
    },
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.2",
        Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node {Name="2.1" },
            new Node {Name="2.2" },
            new Node {Name="2.3" },
        }
    },
};
```

I supposed that it should recursively traverse all levels.
After adding it should be something like this.

```
nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
{
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.1",
    },
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.2",
        Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node {Name="2.1" },
            new Node {Name="2.2" },
            //After adding
            new Node 
            {
                Name="2.3",
                Child = new ObservableCollection<Node> 
                {
                    new Node {Name = "3" } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Func(ObservableCollection<Node> list, string value_for_search, string value_for_add)
{
    foreach (var node in list)
    {
        if (node.Name == value_for_search)
        {
            node.Children ??= new ObservableCollection<Node>(); // Create collection if null
            node.Children.Add(new Node { Name = value_for_add }); // Add a new child node
        }

        if (node.Child != null)
        {
            Func(node.Child, value_for_search, value_for_add); // Recurse
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But for object where there is no `Child`-field or field `value_for_add` dynamicly created doesnt work.

Comment: @QuintusFabiusMaximus _"for object where there is no `Child`-field"_ I'm not sure what that means exactly. Do you mean you need to use types other than `Node`? Because all `Node` objects will have a `Child` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a general-purpose method, which enumerates entire node hierarchy:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Child { get; set; }

    public void Add(Node node)
    {
        if (Child == null)
            Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        Child.Add(node);
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<Node> Hierarchy(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
    {
        if (nodes == null)
            yield break;
        foreach(var node in nodes)
        {
            yield return node;
            foreach(var child in Node.Hierarchy(node.Child))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then use Linq method to search nodes by name:

```
var parent = Node.Hierarchy(nodes).FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "2.3");
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.Add(new Node { Name = "3" });
}
```